# Iphone X css issue in ionic3.8.0

Tags: ionic3, iphone-x

I am using ionic 3.8.0, and I find that when alert is present in iphoneX, the top and the grey backdrop of alert have a gap like the image below, everyone know how to fix it? thanks a lot.
[image]

info:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.15.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.15.2
global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 
local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.1
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.8.0
System:
ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
ios-sim    : 5.0.13 
Node       : v7.10.0
npm        : 5.5.1 
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.0.1 Build version 9A1004 
nvironment Variables:

ANDROID_HOME : not set
Misc:

backend : legacy
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135144/ionic-3-statusbar-top-gap-on-iphone-x-w-simulator

Comment: Thanks @SurajRao, it works

Comment: @SurajRao I use the method that you provided and iOS is working fine now. But I discover when I build android app, the statusbar of android will disappear the information, just remain the black blank statusbar.

Comment: @Nulra Were you able to fix the android status bar problem? I have the same problem in my app.

Comment: @toxinlabs i am using cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar and it solve my problem