# Ionic 3 statusbar top gap on Iphone X (w/ simulator)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ios11, iphone-x

Is there any working trick to solve this design bug?

I'm using cordova-plugin-ionic-webview, "viewport-fit=cover" has been added to index.html.

[image: Bug screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is related to the status bar plugin , which was fixed and merged successfully but it didn't release yet. you can try that plugin directly , for that you need to remove the plugin and installing it from the github url `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar`

More info refer [this issue](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/pull/87)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works :)

Comment: @Webruster HI, I use the method that you provided and iOS is working fine now. But I discover when I build android app, the statusbar of android will disappear the information, just remain the black blank statusbar.

Comment: @Nulra open a  new question and provide more details so that i can help u out

Comment: @Webruster Here is my question, thanks a lot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47050458/iphone-x-css-issue-in-ionic3-8-0?noredirect=1#comment81220743_47050458